# Encounter deadlock even when there is no relation between tables

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock

I've been studying about deadlock and it's different causes .
I found an example regarding this issue but I could not understand the cause of the deadlock exactly because two DIFFERENT tables are involved and what I have read so far was when only one table is involved !!

First I run This Query in Connection 1 :

```
Begin Tran

 Update  Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
 Set Freight = Freight * 0.9
 Where PurchaseOrderID = 1255;
```

Again I run this query in connection 2 :

```
update Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
Set OrderQty = 4
Where ProductID = 448 and
      PurchaseOrderID = 1255
```

and back in connection 1 I run this query  (which leads to the deadlock):

```
Begin Transaction

             Update Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
             Set OrderQty = 2
             where ProductID = 448 and
                   PurchaseOrderID = 1255
```

As you can see , there are two tables involved in the transaction , So what exactly causes the deadlock??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

> I could not understand the cause of the deadlock exactly because two
>   DIFFERENT tables are involved and what I have read so far was when
>   only one table is involved !!

Deadlocks occur when 2 or more sessions are waiting on each other. It doesn't matter if the deadlocked resources are rows in the same table, different tables, entire objects, etc.

I ran your scripts to reproduce the deadlock, extracted the `xml_deadlock_report` column from the `system_health` XE trace, and saved the deadlock report XML to a file with an `.xdl` extension. Below is the graphical view from SSMS.

[image: xml_deadlock_report]

As you can see, the SPID 58 victim was waiting on a `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail` update keylock, blocked by the SPID 53 exclusive keylock on the same key. SPID 53 was waiting on an update keylock on `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader`, blocked by the exclusive lock SPID 58 held on the same key.

Below is the raw xml_deadlock_report XML.

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process1a668c9eca8"/>
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process1a668c9eca8" taskpriority="0" logused="400" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594048348160 (4ab5f0d47ad5)" waittime="1316" ownerId="2500187" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-07-24T06:02:13.303" XDES="0x1a85b00c490" lockMode="U" schedulerid="3" kpid="2932" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-07-24T06:02:31.437" lastbatchcompleted="2018-07-24T06:02:31.433" lastattention="2018-07-24T06:00:22.400" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="SQLSERVER" hostpid="15904" loginname="DOMAINNAME\USERNAME" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2500187" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="64" stmtend="278" sqlhandle="0x02000000d0c7f31a30fb1ad425c34357fe8ef6326793e7aa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="26" stmtend="326" sqlhandle="0x02000000b66e4532b6686980baf466a9597258f2464dd4f50000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>               Update Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail               Set OrderQty = 2               where ProductID = 448 and                     PurchaseOrderID = 1255   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1a66883d848" taskpriority="0" logused="9484" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594048413696 (4bc08edebc6b)" waittime="16176" ownerId="2500193" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-07-24T06:02:16.577" XDES="0x1a85e004490" lockMode="U" schedulerid="5" kpid="20416" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-07-24T06:02:16.577" lastbatchcompleted="2018-07-24T06:02:16.570" lastattention="2018-07-24T06:01:28.820" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="SQLSERVER" hostpid="15904" loginname="DOMAINNAME\USERNAME" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2500193" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673319008" clientoption2="390200">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="AdventureWorks2014.Purchasing.uPurchaseOrderDetail" line="39" stmtstart="2732" stmtend="3830" sqlhandle="0x0300060004cc856a0ee00a016ba3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  UPDATE [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader]              SET [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader].[SubTotal] =                   (SELECT SUM([Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail].[LineTotal])                      FROM [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail]                      WHERE [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader].[PurchaseOrderID]                           = [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail].[PurchaseOrderID])              WHERE [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader].[PurchaseOrderID]                   IN (SELECT inserted.[PurchaseOrderID] FROM inserted    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="3" stmtstart="64" stmtend="278" sqlhandle="0x02000000d0c7f31a30fb1ad425c34357fe8ef6326793e7aa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="3" stmtstart="28" stmtend="250" sqlhandle="0x02000000cac3a70ebbbc20e8360adb397f4986f2ced020140000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>  Begin Tran    update Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail  Set OrderQty = 4  Where ProductID = 448 and        PurchaseOrderID = 1255   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594048348160" dbid="6" objectname="AdventureWorks2014.Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail" indexname="PK_PurchaseOrderDetail_PurchaseOrderID_PurchaseOrderDetailID" id="lock1a7fea46a00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594048348160">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1a66883d848" mode="X"/>
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1a668c9eca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594048413696" dbid="6" objectname="AdventureWorks2014.Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader" indexname="PK_PurchaseOrderHeader_PurchaseOrderID" id="lock1a815dda900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594048413696">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1a668c9eca8" mode="X"/>
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1a66883d848" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

The sample `AdventureWorks` database includes an `UPDATE` trigger on `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail` table that contributed to this deadlock. The trigger inserts into `Production.TransactionHistory` and also updates both `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader` and `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail` whenever `ProductID`, `OrderQty`, or `UnitPrice` columns are updated.

In summary, the sequence leading to this deadlock was:

1) connection 1 updated a `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader` but did not commit

2) connection 2 updated the `Purchasing.PurchaseDetail` table and the fired trigger was blocked when trying to update `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader`

3) connection 1 tried to update `Purchasing.PurchaseDetail` but was blocked by connection

4) SQL Server chose connection 1 as the deadlock victim, allowing connection 2 to autocommit

Answer (score 0):

I repeat your example, I run `connection`1 then run `connection 2`.Even `connection 2` is not able to complete.

Though both table are different `connection 2` is still block because **`PurchaseOrderID is Trusted Foreign Key`**

If I rollback Trans and repeat the Experiment.
Connection 1 query is same.

connection 2 query ,(notice I have kept different PurchaseOrderID than connection 1)

```
update Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
Set OrderQty = 4
Where ProductID = 359 and
      PurchaseOrderID = 2
```

Now I fire both connection in similar manner..
`Both connection` complete successfully this time. Because of different PurchaseOrderID value.

All triggers are fired and also I can view record of PurchaseOrderID=2 in TransactionHistory table

If we remove `FK` from `PurchaseOrderID` then there won't be any Deadlock.

So deadlock can happen because of `Trusted FK`  if any `Transaction` is not  handle properly.

Though Trusted FK is very helpful in execution plan.

There can be several reason for deadlock.

@Guzman, sorry If my language is confusing or not clear.

See in this example, If I disable both Trigger

connection 1 query continue to run because it is not yet `Committed` or `Rollback`

connection 2 query also continue to run because it is not yet `Committed` or `Rollback`.Though both table are different.Connection 2 query do not auto commit.

Deadlock or block is not because of trigger.

In this example Deadlock is because of Trusted Foreign key as I have tried to explain above.

IMO,If there is Trusted FK,and both parent and child tables are updated and also transaction is not handle properly then deadlock will occur .

Comment: Regarding your edit, there should be no `BEGIN TRAN` in the connection 2 query per the original question. The connection 2 update query will then autocommit immediately (since the trigger is disabled, it's not blocked), releasing locked resources. The second connection 1 update can complete, followed by a COMMIT/ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been studying about deadlock and it's different causes

There is *only one* cause of a Deadlock.

Two process each have exclusive control of one resource and want exclusive control of another one, held by the other process.  In the database world, these resources are usually locks on records.

Process 1 locks row 1 in Table A.

Process 2 locks row 2 in Table B.

Being Transactional, neither will give up their control of these locks until commit [or rollback] is issued.

Each now wants to lock the row that the other *already has* locked - Process 1 wants to lock row 2 in Table B and Process 2 wants to lock row 1 in Table A.  If the locks were on *different* rows, the deadlock would not happen.

The two processes enter a "deadly embrace" from which neither can ever escape; each will wait forever for the other to release its lock, which will never happen.  The DBMS detects this situation and kills one of the processes, usually at random, allowing the other to complete.

There does not need to be any logical relationship between the two tables involved, only that they exist and that rows within them are locked "out of sequence" by the two processes.

This is why careful Application design is essential, making sure that updates are [generally] applied in "the same order", to avoid exactly this situation.  If both Processes updated Table A and Table B in the same order, then the deadlock could be completely avoided.